# Sending mail right after 12 hours, Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, queue, laravel-5.1, scheduler

I want to send an email to a user, right after 12 hours of registration. How should I go about it?

1. Don't want to check user registration time via Laravel scheduler (every minute or every 5 minutes).
2. Can't use delayed Queues, as SQS and others can only handle max 15 mins of delay.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only SQS has 15 mins of limitations.

Comment: Can't you use a cronjob?

Comment: I want to avoid searching all the newly joined users via cron everytime. Looking for more efficient solution.

Comment: You could use a table specifically for the emails? When a user registers they go in to your users table and this temp table and then use cron and scheduler to grab them after 12 hours and then delete the record after that.
That way you wouldn't have heaps of users as there would only be a max of 12 hours worth of registrations at any one time.